# IIS 7 Faulting application name: w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We have created a website using WCSF framework and .NET 2.0.

Currently this application is live and used by more than 1000 users. We have deployed this in a cloud in IIS 7 under Windows 2008 Server R2. We also use Sql Server 2008 R2 database for the backend. The deployment architecture is as described below.

There are two web servers connected under a load balancer (Hardware based) using sticky sessions. These two servers communicates with two database servers with more than 600 databases scattered evenly between them. All requests will first go to a admin database which redirects to the appropriate db server.

**Now to the issue....**

We are getting around 4 to 5 w3wp crashes per day in both the servers. During this time all the users connected to the application will be logged out.

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time
>   stamp: 0x4ce7afa2 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1677 Exception code: 0xe053534f Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d Faulting process id: 0x%9 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x%10 Faulting application path: %11 Faulting
>   module path: %12 Report Id: %13

Recently we opened a case with MS and their comments is given below.

**---Begin Microsoft response---**

The process crashed due to Stack Overflow issue.

.Net Call Stack:

```
System.Enum.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider)
System.Convert.ToInt64(System.Object, System.IFormatProvider)
System.Enum.ToUInt64(System.Object)
System.Enum.IsDefined(System.Type, System.Object)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.Locator.Get(System.Object, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.SearchMode)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReadableLocator.Get[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Object)
<Trimmed>
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
```

Full Call Stack

We are seeing that the call is made for the URL :- ASP.xxxdashboards_recordlistview_aspx

```
ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess
KERNELBASE!TerminateProcess+2f
mscorwks!EEPolicy::HandleFatalStackOverflow+13b
mscorwks!EEPolicy::HandleStackOverflow+212
mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler+3de1be
mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim+42
ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+a8
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+22
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+2e
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+39
mscorwks!AllocateObject+34aeb1
mscorwks!MethodTable::FastBox+43
mscorwks!MethodTable::Box+5b
mscorwks!ReflectionEnum::InternalGetEnumValue+139
System.Enum.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider)+b
System.Convert.ToInt64(System.Object, System.IFormatProvider)+35
System.Enum.ToUInt64(System.Object)+9d
System.Enum.IsDefined(System.Type, System.Object)+ff
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.Locator.Get(System.Object, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.SearchMode)+4d
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReadableLocator.Get[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Object)+10
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+11f
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+2be
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+2be
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+2be
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+2be
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+2be

<Trimmed>

Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+28e
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+28e
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+56
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)+28e
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.ObjectBuilder.WCSFBuilderBase`1[[Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.ObjectBuilder.WCSFBuilderStage, Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb]].DoBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IReadWriteLocator, System.Type, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.PolicyList[])+13a
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.ObjectBuilder.WCSFBuilderBase`1[[Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.ObjectBuilder.WCSFBuilderStage, Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb]].BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IReadWriteLocator, System.Type, System.String, System.Object, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.PolicyList[])+64
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.CompositionContainer.BuildItem(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilder`1<Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.ObjectBuilder.WCSFBuilderStage>, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IReadWriteLocator, System.Object)+334
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication.BuildItemWithCurrentContext(System.Object)+121
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Web.UI.UserControl.OnInit(System.EventArgs)+3f
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+8f
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(System.Web.UI.Control, Int32)+10f
DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl.Internal.PCContentsControl.CreateControlHierarchy()+2ae
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.CreateChildControls()+33

<Trimmed>
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()+92
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()+9
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()+d
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control, Boolean)+3e
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control, Boolean)+d0
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+25
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.CreateChildControls()+166
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()+92
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()+9
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.IASPxWebControl.EnsureChildControls()+d
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control, Boolean)+3e
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.RenderUtils.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control, Boolean)+d0
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControlsRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+25
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.CreateChildControls()+166
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()+92
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControlBase.EnsureChildControls()+9
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.InitInternal()+48
DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.OnInit(System.EventArgs)+1c
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+8f
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(System.Web.UI.Control)+187
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean)+5c5
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean)+a0
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()+5b
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+f0
ASP.xxxdashboards_recordlistview_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+9
```

We are seeing the following code in a tight recursive loop which is eventually leading into StackOverflow situation.

```
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.ContainerAwareTypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IBuilderContext, System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
```

Further, they also added the following.
Looked into the code to see the infinite loop and here seems to be the case
Inside Microsoft_Practices_CompositeWeb!Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.BuilderStrategies.SessionStateBindingStrategy

```
public override object BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, object existing, string idToBuild)
{
    ISessionStateLocatorService service = context.Locator.(object);" href="http://www.aisto.com/roeder/dotnet/Default.aspx?Target=code://Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder:1.0.51206.0:b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.IReadableLocator/Get<>(Object):"Get<ISessionStateLocatorService>(new DependencyResolutionLocatorKey(typeof(ISessionStateLocatorService), null));
    if (service != null)
    {
        IHttpSessionState sessionState = service.GetSessionState();
        foreach (FieldInfo info in typeToBuild.GetFields())
        {
            this.SetFieldValue(existing, info, sessionState);
        }
    }
    return base.BuildUp(context, typeToBuild, existing, idToBuild);
}
```

So this calls the BuildUp defined in Microsoft_Practices_ObjectBuilder!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy

```
public virtual object BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, object existing, string idToBuild)
{
    IBuilderStrategy nextInChain = context.GetNextInChain(this);
    if (nextInChain != null)
    {
        return nextInChain.BuildUp(context, typeToBuild, existing, idToBuild);
    }
    return existing;
}
```

This results in infinite loop.

**---End Microsoft response---**

We are not sure where to look for the issue at the moment and if anybody could help us to solve the issue it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."

Comment: It looks like Microsoft has given you very good direction.  They have shown you where your code is encountering an infite recursive loop (resulting in a StackOverflow exception).

Comment: @zero323 I don't see how this is even slightly on-topic for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with IIS Crash and exception code "0xc00000fd". I recommend that you catch a crash dump.

1) Install a software to get a crash dump. I recommend  the [DebugDiag Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933).

2) After the installation, configure the **DebugDiag Tool** following these instructions:

- Selecting a Crash rule Selecting a IIS App pool (w3wp.exe)
- Selecting the app pool of application
- Configuring a Stack over flow
  exception (0xc00000fd) in Advanced Settings/Exceptions and finish 
  the setup.

3) Wait for a first crash dump to be created in folder location. Ex: C:\DebugDiag\Logs. When the crash dump was created, use the **DebugDiag Analysis** to open the file from C:\DebugDiag\Logs and a HTML report will be created.

4) In report you see quickly the problem in analysis summary on the top of the page. In my case, there was a recursive function without stop conditional that leading the app poll fall.